# Is there a VS Code extension like intelliSense that will autocomplete outlook conditional code rather than commenting it out?

Tags: visual-studio-code, html-email, intellisense, vscode-extensions, html-editor

I'm currently learning HTML email development, and I've come to learning about Outlook Conditional statements. The problem is that VS Code reads these as a comment and does not auto-complete anything (automatically closing tags etc). This adds a lot of work and opens the code up to errors. Is there an extension like IntelliSense that addresses this problem?

`<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]> <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation" > <![endif]-->`

Every character of the code above has to be typed out, and the closing tags typed manually, there has to be a better way.

Tried IntelliSense setting, tried searching the extensions marketplace in Visual Studio Code, searched on google and stack overflow

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to create one! :)

Comment: The only real email editor that might do this is parcel for email. Otherwise you'd have to create this

Comment: That’s just the legacy non-standard IE related conditions so not widely supported. If you don’t write your own extension, you will need to see if anyone would spare the time implementing it.